# Cards' Rank-Order Probability Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables, card-games

The question is short but it may be a little bit tricky:

Suppose we have a deck that contains n cards with n different rank (let's say ranks are 1, 2, ... , n), and then we randomly shuffle the deck, what's the probability that all cards' orders are different from their ranks?

Such as:

$1^{st}$ card cannot be the card with rank 1, and

$2^{nd}$ card cannot be the card with rank 2, and

... and

$n^{th}$ card cannot be the card with rank n.

I have done some simulations for a specific n (n=7), feel free to use the sample probability distribution to test against your thoughts:

```
> n <- rep(-1, 1000000)
> for (i in 1:length(n)) {
+   deck <- sample(1:7)
+   n[i] <- sum(sample(1:7) == 1:7)
+ }
> table(n) / length(n)
n
       0        1        2        3        4        5        7 
0.367319 0.368180 0.183299 0.062795 0.014050 0.004150 0.000207
```

Comment: Look up derangements in Wikipedia.